# Should we keep allowing people who use android to also use the java tag in questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Whenever I search java questions on stackoverflow that are tagged to try an answer I run across hundreds of ones that are mainly about android. Which raises the issue that while android is like java, android is [not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API) java.

Thus I have to search sometimes about 5 pages before coming across an actual java question that is not an actual android question.

My question is as follows. Is tagging android questions as java degrading the ability for people's java questions to get answered as they are pushed down by tons of android questions, in addition to should we allow android questions to be continued to be tagged as android?

Comment: As a workaround, you can add android to your ignored tags.  Or use the search feature with something like `[java] -[android]`

Comment: @ryanyuyu that is very true, but i wonder how many users know to do this. i mean i am not partial to either side but thought it might be a good discussion, to get some input on if this is kinda mistagging a question.

Comment: The sloppy tagging is an issue. You could probably get an [tag:android] tag badge without actually knowing much about Android. Similarly the [tag:android-studio] often gets added to questions that are not about Android Studio. Both OP's and editors should pay more attention.

Answer (score 4):

I think they should only be marked as 'Java' if there's reasonable amount of Java language content in the question - i.e. it's not a question that covers the Android specific libraries or Dalvik / ART.

This would be similar to questions on say LWJGL - if it's mainly a question on using OpenGL library functions, it probably shouldn't be tagged. But if it's a question where Java knowledge is useful / helpful, it should be.

Comment: I partially agree with this assessment, given that there are some Android-based questions which are still Java questions at heart.  However, it can be tough to tell the difference, especially for those of us who are accustomed to finding NPEs in one way and Android developers are used to it in another.